# Merge lists of lists in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, declarative, declarative-programming

I would like to perform something like:

```
merge([[[],[],[],[t1]],[[],[],[],[t2,t3]]], X).
```

where X would return as: `[[],[],[],[t1,t2,t3]]`.

But I have tried everything to my prolog knowledge and came up with nothing.

Any hints?

Imagine it as:

```
Computer(
    Tasklist1(
            core1[sometasks],core2[sometasks],...,coreX(sometasks)), 
    ...
    TasklistX(
            core1[sometasks],core2[sometasks],...,coreX(sometasks))
)
```

so the tasklist after tasklist1 needs to be scheduled on the same cores, after the tasks of tasklist1.

Comment: And `[[[1],[2],[3]], [[4],[5],[6]]]` would yield `[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]`?

Comment: (Why are the "leaves" in the first argument lists?)

Comment: yes, indeed! you just 'append' every X'th element of every list

Comment: You can imagine that each list that you get is a processor core, and the numbers are tasks. the tasks are wrapped in lists to clarify that those are the tasks for 1 core.

Comment: But each "inner" list must be a single element?

Comment: The format of input is always of the following:

[ [[],[], ...], [[],[], ...], ... ] and no deeper.

Imagine it as in the example of my question, I edited it for you.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you're after.

Comment: Oh dear! i have a typo! look at my question again please :o

Comment: So your example of merge([[[1],[2],[3]], [[4],[5],[6]]]) would  still yield [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67789/discussion-between-valentijn-spruyt-and-aioobe).

Comment: Were any of the answers acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not totally clear what the limits of the problem may be. But here is a solution which assumes you may have more than two inner list-of-lists, and the count of the innermost lists might vary.

```
merge2(L, [], L) :- L \= [].
merge2([], L, L).
merge2([LH1|LT1], [LH2|LT2], [LH3|LT3]) :-
    append(LH1, LH2, LH3),
    merge2(LT1, LT2, LT3).

merge([L], L).
merge([H1,H2|T], R) :-
    merge2(H1, H2, H),
    merge([H|T], R).
```

So,

```
| ?- merge([[[],[],[],[t1]],[[],[],[],[t2,t3]]], L).

L = [[],[],[],[t1,t2,t3]] ? ;

no
| ?- merge([[[1],[2],[3]], [[4],[5],[6]],[[a],[b],[c,d]]], L).

L = [[1,4,a],[2,5,b],[3,6,c,d]] ? a

no
| ?- merge([[[1],[2],[3]], [[5],[6]],[[a],[b],[c,d]]], L).

L = [[1,5,a],[2,6,b],[3,c,d]] ? ;

(1 ms) no
| ?-
```

If you want to restrict the innermost list counts to be the same, you can replace `merge2` with `maplist`, and the `merge` predicate simply becomes:

```
merge([L], L).
merge([H1,H2|T], R) :-
    maplist(append, H1, H2, H),
    merge([H|T], R).
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. sorry for the late reply

Comment: @ValentijnSpruyt no worries. You can also simplify the solution using `maplist` if inner list counts are the same, per my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

I thought it could be easier...

```
merge(L, R) :-
    maplist(length_list(N), L),
    findall(S, (
        between(1,N,I),
        findall(Zs, (
            member(Z,L),
            nth1(I,Z,Zs)), T),
        append(T, S)), R).

length_list(Len, L) :- length(L, Len).
```